# git status is reporting files it should ignore

Tags: git, macos

My git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61) which is running OSX 10.11.2 is reporting **files in red** which it is expected to ignore according to the content  ***.txt** of .gitignore, please see below;

[image]

Please help fix this.

Thank you

Comment: "_Files already tracked by Git are not affected_ [by .gitignore]". Were the files added before .gitignore was changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files are already known to your repository (were added previously), so `git` does track the state of these files. The `.gitignore` serves for filtering out any unknown yet files by matching with name templates listed.

So, either do `git rm` for these files and then `commit` or `add` the changed versions and `commit` according to your needs.